# Не подключается к Mysql из DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Использую Laravel Homestead

пытаюсь подключиться к базе но пишет

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, указывается неверный хост/порт. В качестве хоста можно использовать IP, указанный в Homestead.yaml, порт - 3306